# org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

When I execute the code, its showing `org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only`. But its not rolling back.

**My Code:**

**Service level**

```
public void checkTransaction(Users user) throws Exception {
    adminDao.insertUser(user);
    System.out.println("Transaction active :: " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
    throw (new Exception("Testing Transaction"));
}
```

**xml**

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Exception" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceOperation"
        expression="execution(* myapp.admin.service.AdminService.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceOperation" />
</aop:config>
```

**POJO**

My POJO (Users) Bean is not a annotated one, its mapped to hbm file. But it is registered in mapping resources.

```
<bean id="mysessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>myapp/admin/vo/Users.hbm.xml</value></list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: `rollback-for="java.lang.Exception"` maybe?

Comment: Nope. Not working. Showing the same error.

Comment: There could be an exception in your `adminDao.insertUser(user)` method. Check if its working.

Comment: Actually its a test function. I want to know whether it is working properly or not. In my case 'adminDao.insertUser(user)' is working fine, its inserting data into database. Next line is throwing excetion(manually- for checking purpose). According to my transaction advice its need to roll back, but its not.

Comment: Anyone please? _Help me to solve_

Comment: Debug into this method and see what's happening: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor.html#invoke-org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation-

Comment: how do you define which services this `txAdvice` is applied to? i.e `aop:config`

Comment: @Sethu, Yes. I am using aop:config

Comment: My transactional layer is in service layer, so that i can manage multiple dao transactions.

Comment: My POJO (Users) Bean is not a annotated one, its mapped to hbm file. will it cause any problem?? But it is registered in mapping resources.

Comment: Do you observe the same behavior if you throw a RuntimeException rather than an Exception ?

Comment: @Thierry: No. But its not rolling back either. Its showing `java.lang.RuntimeException: Testing Transaction` error

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from the same problem. What happens is that in the Service layer you can not make a query of type select and after it, an insert.
You need to separate the processes. In my case, declare a component class and, through it, call the processes of my service separately.
I hope it is useful for you ;)

Comment: True if it's in the same transaction.